# POST запрос с HTTP basic аутентификацией

Tags: c#, http, request

Есть *POST*-запрос:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
request.Headers.Add( String.Format("Content-Length : {0}", smsXml.Length));
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(smsParams);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream2);

//результат запроса
string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
stream2.Close();
```

Сюда нужно добавить аутентификацию  *HTTP basic*.

Я находил пример с использованием *WebProxy*, а вот как доработать этот кусок кода?

Насколько я понимаю, нужно просто логин/пароль передать с запросом?

Comment: HTTP basic auth - это просто заголовк Authorization cо значеним в виде bsae64-кодированной строки username:password

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно создать `NetworkCredential`:

```cs
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("VasyaPupkin", "qwerty");
```

И установить его в качестве свойства `Credentials`:

```cs
request.Credentials = credentials;
```

Собственно это - всё, что необходимо для basic-авторизации.

К слову, рекомендую перейти на использование `HttpClient`'а вместо `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse` - у него более богатый функционал, что позволяет писать (возможно субъективно) более простой для понимания код:

```cs
var smsParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "message", "privet, bla-bla-bla" },
    { "foo", "bar" },
    { "baz", "quux" }
};


using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    handler.Credentials = credentials;

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(smsParams);
        var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

        // результат запроса в виде строки
        result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```